# FSharp Data - issues with FSharp Core on prod server

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am using the latest FSharp.Data package in a mixed F#/C# project and I have an issue on my prod server with FSharp Core when moving the bin directory over.

> 2015-04-13 22:09:24,405 [11972] WARN  xxx.xxxImpl -  Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
>   File name: 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I installed the latest official .NET 4.5.1 and Visual F# Tools 3.1.2 on the server, but this was not good enough. What would you suggest? I use VS 2013 with F# Power tools on my dev machine and this works fine.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541058/net-runtime-tries-to-load-fsharp-core-4-3-0-even-if-all-projects-reference-4-3/29542285#29542285

Comment: I decided to downgrade Target F# runtime of the dlls, so that FSharp Core is matching. This does the deal.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when upgrading F# versions a hard coded reference to the old version can be left in the project. My solution has always been to open the F# .proj file in text editor and remove the fixed reference element to the old Core dll.