# How can I use FSharp.Core 4.3 with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Tags: c#, f#, deedle

I want to use Deedle, but it complains like this:

> Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly
>   'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' because it has not been preloaded.
>   When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be
>   pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the
>   ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.'

Being an Android developer normally I'm a bit confused about VS dependencies.
I tried with the Package Manager Console, but it installs only 4.0.0.1 and doesn't know 4.3.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is solved with help from this question:

[.NET runtime tries to load FSharp.Core 4.3.0 even if all projects reference 4.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541058/net-runtime-tries-to-load-fsharp-core-4-3-0-even-if-all-projects-reference-4-3)

In the App.config file there was a binding redirect already to 4.4.0.0. I don't know if I added it earlier or Deedle. When I changed it to 4.0.0.1, which is apparently and confusingly the latest version of FSharp and I could download it with NuGet, it started to work.